# How to make search menu item to a full view in the action bar using abs

Tags: android, action, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have five action menu items in the action bar, which I'm using action bar sherlock library as follows :

In `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, i used the following code :

```
  menu.add(0,1,0 "Settings")
      .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

  menu.add(0,2,0 "Favorites")
      .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

  menu.add(0,3,0 "List")
      .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

  menu.add(0,4,0 "Upload")
      .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

  menu.add(0,5,0 "Search")
     .setActionView(R.layout.search_layout)
     .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

Now my Problem is Search Edit text (which is in red color) appears like this:
[image: Search edit text appears like this]

I want to make it to a full view in the action bar, like this :

[image: Expected output]

Comment: You are setting other items as `SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS`, obviously there's not enough space left for collapsible search item.

Answer (score 6):

This question is a bit old but I'll try to answer it anyway. I hope someone will find it useful.

Here is what I have done:

**Create a custom SearchView class that extends SearchView**. It defines 2 events: one fired when the search view expands and the other when it collapses.

```
public class EnglishVerbSearchView extends SearchView {

OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener;
OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener;

public EnglishVerbSearchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
    if (mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener != null)
        mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener.onSearchViewCollapsed();
    super.onActionViewCollapsed();
}

@Override
public void onActionViewExpanded() {
    if (mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener != null)
        mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener.onSearchViewExpanded();
    super.onActionViewExpanded();
}

public interface OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener {
    public void onSearchViewCollapsed();
}

public interface OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener {
    public void onSearchViewExpanded();
}

public void setOnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener(OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener eventListener) {
    mSearchViewCollapsedEventListener = eventListener;
}

public void setOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener(OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener eventListener) {
    mOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener = eventListener;
}

}
```

**In my activity**, I did the following:
- Created a private field to store the reference to the menu.
- Defined the events for collapsing and expanding the search view where I hide and show other actions by using the reference to the menu.

```
public class DictionaryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Menu mMenu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dictionary, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    EnglishVerbSearchView searchView = (EnglishVerbSearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);        

    searchView.setOnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener(listenerCollapse);
    searchView.setOnSearchViewExpandedEventListener(listenerExpand);

    mMenu = menu;

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

final private OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener listenerCollapse = new OnSearchViewCollapsedEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSearchViewCollapsed() {
        // show other actions
        MenuItem favouriteItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favourite);
        MenuItem playItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_play);
        favouriteItem.setVisible(true);
        playItem.setVisible(true);

        // I'm doing my actual search here          
    }
};

final private OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener listenerExpand = new OnSearchViewExpandedEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSearchViewExpanded() {
        // hide other actions
        MenuItem favouriteItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_favourite);
        MenuItem playItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_play);
        favouriteItem.setVisible(false);
        playItem.setVisible(false);
    }
};

}
```

In the menu.xml file, I used the custom search view:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
      yourapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
      yourapp:actionViewClass="com.xxx.EnglishVerbSearchView" />
</menu>
```

I hope it's all that's needed as it's just an extract from my full code of the activity. Let me know if there's anything missing.

---

As per comment from arne.jans:

It seems to be enough to do `MenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);` to make room for the `SearchView`. The advantage would be: the other menu-items go into the overflow menu and are still accessible, even with the opened `SearchView`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just a note: it seems to be enough to do

MenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

to make room for the SearchView. The advantage would be: the other menu-items go into the overflow menu and are still accessible, even with the opened SearchView.

Comment: @arne.jans Thanks! I added it to my answer, thanks for improving it.

Comment: If I use your approach, the app crashes with a NPE accessing null searchView in activity.onCreateOptionsMenu on certain devices running Android 4.0-4.1.2.

Did you have this problem, too?

Just before this NPE, the Logs show the following exception as a warning (which is strange, since I definitely have the right public constructor with param Context):

    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)

Comment: @arne.jans No, I didn't have this problem. I used this approach in my app and I didn't have crash reports. Maybe you could create a separate question with your code.

Comment: I am doing an additional supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() after setting visibility and onCreateOptionsMenu is called again afterwards, maybe that is the problem.
I also tried setting the custom SearchView in code with MenuItemCompat.setActionView(MenuItem, View). Does it trigger your menuitem-visibility correctly without calling supportInvalidateOptionsMenu?

Comment: I found that if I don't call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu afterwards, it works correctly, thanks again!

Comment: how would you get the text from the search view?