# Android SearchView with other items in ActionBar

Tags: android, searchview

I am using Android SearchView as a second item in the actionbar item layout. When it is expanded the first item stays visible. Therefore the area for the searchview will be smaller. It does not take the whole width of the screen.

What can I do to make it full-width? Thank you.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I guess the only way is to hide them manually.

Comment: Wow!  That's absolutely crazy.  But I can't find anything better.  Thanks (points for you)!

Comment: Putting SearchView to the leftmost position is a solution too. :) Thank you for the point.

Comment: Check my answer to a similar question:
[See another question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660225/how-to-make-search-menu-item-to-a-full-view-in-the-action-bar-using-abs/18648708#18648708