# How to make the Action Bar SearchView fill Entire action bar?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, uisearchbar

[image]

I was trying to create an [action bar search](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) in my application, but in the expanded state the [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) is not taking the entire action bar width( it is still showing other actions)!

So, how to make the SearchView fill the full ActionBar Area (as in GMAIL app)?

Comment: use actionBarSherLock ..

Comment: Check my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660225/how-to-make-search-menu-item-to-a-full-view-in-the-action-bar-using-abs/18648708#18648708

Comment: I am creating this app for 4.0 and above, so i don't think  i need to use actionBarSherLock! Is there way to do this in normal actionBar?

Comment: Yes, there is. Check my comment above.

Comment: @st. Ok i will check it.. what is this "yourapp"?

Comment: "yourapp" is just an XML namespace. You can change it to something more suitable :)

Comment: I only found out that searchView.setMaxWidth(4000); will fill all the space, but it will hide other item

Answer (score 30):

None of the above solutions worked for me. Setting the MaxWidth of the SearchView worked for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: This has the downside that even the overflow menu button disappears on API level 23. Tested in the emulator.

Comment: hm this is a weird question because I want to do the opposite, and default behavior seems to be max value for me right now....

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Got it

[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_swipe_tabbed, menu);

    MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchViewItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    searchView.setLayoutParams(params);
    searchViewItem.expandActionView();
    return true;
}


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MySwipeTabbedActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="Search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
            android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
            />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
            android:title="Share"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:title="Settings"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

[Optional] Avoid the searchView from collapsing:

```
    searchViewItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            return false; //never collapse
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer is working for me :) one add n for this answer is that to avoid collapsing when we use app compact lib its should be like this  MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchViewItem, new OnActionExpandListener() ....... otherwise the app will crash

Comment: To add to this, if you're using the new Toolbar API, you would change it to: final ActionMenuView.LayoutParams lp = new ActionMenuView.LayoutParams(ActionMenuView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionMenuView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

Comment: @Ramz It's not working for me. I tried this [in this SSCCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994512/how-to-make-the-distance-between-left-edge-of-toolbar-and-search-icon-same-as-th), but didn't work. I'll really appreciate if you can look into it.

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider I tried that as well [in this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994512/how-to-make-the-distance-between-left-edge-of-toolbar-and-search-icon-same-as-th) but did not help. Can you look into it?

Answer (score 2):

The Answer given by @Hiep is correct i followed those steps to get my solution.but i was using ActionbarCompact lib so it take some changes to made so that i get it to work **This solution is only the modified answer of Hiep if you are using appcompact**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="search"
      android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
      materialdesign:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
      materialdesign:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

And in the Main Class **onCreateOptionsMenu**

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_swipe_tabbed, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);



    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    searchView.setLayoutParams(params);
    searchView.setIconified(false);

     MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchItem);

   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Avoid the searchView from collapsing:If u use the above method in Appcompact it will create a crash so use this solution to avoid that.

```
      MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener#onMenuItemActionExpand(android.view.MenuItem)
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {

            return true;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener#onMenuItemActionCollapse(android.view.MenuItem)
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try This Only will work and keep all other items set to ifRoom

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm really late :)
But I would like to share one more alternative solution. The idea is just to hide the grouped menu items when the `SearchView` gets expanded.

**Step 1:**
Group your menu items. Please make sure `showAsAction` of search view item is `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"`

```
<group android:id="@+id/myMenuGroup">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionSearch"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:iconTint="@color/textColorVariant2"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionFilter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="@string/filter"
        app:iconTint="@color/textColorVariant2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

        ..... </group>
```

**Step 2:** Get the menu reference in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` callback

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    this.menu = menu // this.menu is a global scoped variable
    return true
}
```

**Step 3**
Add `MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener` into your activity and implement `onMenuItemActionExpand()` and `onMenuItemActionExpand()` like below

```
override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(p0: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    menu?.setGroupVisible(R.id.myMenuGroup, false)
    return true
}

override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(p0: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    menu?.setGroupVisible(R.id.myMenuGroup, true)
    return true
}
```

This approach will expand the `SearchView` completely inside the `ActionBar` even if there are other `menu` icons present

[image]

[image]